# Data redundancy while using IN clause

Tags: mysql

Why do I receive redundant data while using an `IN` clause:

```
Select * from table1 where ab in (select X from  table2)
```

Comment: It depends. Is ab and/or X a unique key?

Comment: What's the output you're getting?

Comment: What is your data? Why does your data make you think it shouldn't be redundant?

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess because your question isn't very clear. Try using `DISTINCT` as follows:

```
Select * 
  from table1 
 where ab in (select DISTINCT X 
                from table2)
```

That will eliminate duplicate values of `X`, which may help remove duplicate rows in your resultset.

Comment: I believe this will work in the same way as the original query. `IN` works the same whether there are dupes in the sub-query or not.